# Ïs /etc/init.d/transmisssion-daemon file created after transmssion daemon installed, or I should creat it myself?

Tags: transmission

Ïs /etc/init.d/transmisssion-daemon file created after transmssion daemon installed, or I should creat it myself?

I don't see it, so I creat it. but it does not solve my problem.
The daemon still run by user, transmission.

Answer (score 1):

That file should be installed by the `transmission-daemon` package. DO NOT create one yourself.

However, that particular file is also not part of a normal Transmission install anyway.